# Problems with “typing.ClassVar” when using a factory function to generate annotation types in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to use a factory function to generate some type annotations – specifically for `tuple` types. I have one version of the factory that works fine (as in, it compiles, runs, and checks out satisfactorily in MyPy):

```py
import typing as tx
HomogenousTypeVar = tx.TypeVar('HomogenousTypeVar')
TupleTypeReturnType = tx.Type[tx.Tuple[HomogenousTypeVar, ...]]

def TupleType(length: int,
              tuptyp: tx.Type[HomogenousTypeVar] = str) -> TupleTypeReturnType:
    """ Create a type annotation for a tuple of a given type and length """
    assert length > 0
    return tx.Tuple[tuple(tuptyp for idx in range(length))]
```

… for which the usage is like e.g.:

```py
class Thing(object):

    __slots__: TupleType(2) = ('yo', 'dogg')
    other_fields: TupleType(4) = ('i', 'heard',
                                  'you', 'like')

    # etc, or what have you
```

… however, I was unsuccessful when I tried to add support for the `typing.ClassVar` annotation, which looked like this:

```py
import typing as tx
HomogenousTypeVar = tx.TypeVar('HomogenousTypeVar')
TupleTypeReturnType = tx.Union[tx.Type[tx.Tuple[HomogenousTypeVar, ...]],
                               tx.Type[tx.ClassVar[tx.Tuple[HomogenousTypeVar, ...]]]]

def TupleType(length: int,
              tuptyp: tx.Type[HomogenousTypeVar] = str,
              clsvar: bool = False) -> TupleTypeReturnType:
    """ Create a type annotation for a tuple of a given type and length,
        specifying additionally whether or not it is a ClassVar """
    assert length > 0
    out = tx.Tuple[tuple(tuptyp for idx in range(length))]
    return clsvar and tx.ClassVar[out] or out
```

… after this change, the code won’t even initially compile – it fails to do so with a `TypeError` from deep within the `typing` module:

> TypeError: typing.ClassVar[typing.Tuple[~HomogenousTypeVar, ...]] is
>   not valid as type argument

… which, as errors go, strikes me as a little phoned-in; I mean, is not *everything* in `typing` supposed to be a valid type argument in some fashion, give-or-take?

In [the `typing` source code related to `ClassVar`](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/d6631e8ea56063897e341207477e0cc3231f20b2/src/typing.py#L1376-L1430), there are a handful of restrictions to its use mentioned in the docstring – but this is not one of them. Is there something obvious I am missing? Is my attempt to use this annotation in this fashion a quixotic one? What else might I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your original code snippet actually type-checks with mypy? When I try running it using either Mypy 0.620 or the latest version from github, I get the following errors:

```
test.py:13: error: invalid type comment or annotation
test.py:13: note: Suggestion: use TupleType[...] instead of TupleType(...)
test.py:14: error: invalid type comment or annotation
test.py:14: note: Suggestion: use TupleType[...] instead of TupleType(...)
```

I'm also not able to reproduce the error you get with your ClassVar code -- when I try running it, I get the following errors:

```
test.py:4: error: Invalid type: ClassVar nested inside other type
test.py:6: error: Incompatible default for argument "tuptyp" (default has type "Type[str]", argument has type "Type[HomogenousTypeVar]")
test.py:12: error: Invalid type alias
test.py:13: warning: Returning Any from function declared to return "Union[Type[Tuple[HomogenousTypeVar?, ...]], Type[Tuple[HomogenousTypeVar?, ...]]]"
test.py:15: error: Name 'Thing' is not defined
test.py:16: error: Revealed type is 'Any'
```

Are you sure you're actually running mypy, as opposed to just running the code? E.g. if you only run `python3 test.py`, you're basically skipping all type checks (apart from some bare minimum sanity checks built into the typing module).

If you want to type-check your code, you need to pip-install mypy and run `python3 -m mypy test.py`.

---

In any case, all of these error messages are expected behavior -- mypy (and any other PEP 484 compliant type checker) can only analyze your code *statically* and will not attempt to run or analyze any factory functions/any type-hint generation functions you may try and write.

So, this means that unfortunately you won't be able to use your generated type hint with ClassVars if you want PEP 484 compliant tools to be able to analyze your code -- they can't understand/interpret your original set of type hints, and adding ClassVars certainly won't help.

If you want to generate type hints, the only real option I can think of is to invent some sort of mini-language or macro system on top of Python that when run, will generate Python code. You would then run and typecheck that generated code instead of your macrofied Python language.

But I really don't recommend doing this -- it's a very fragile hack.

---

More broadly, whenever you start running into these sorts of type-related limitations, I think it's a sign that your code is too complicated. I would either look into simplifying your code or (if that's not possible) switch to a language like Haskell or Idris which would let you use a more expressive (albeit more complex) type system.

For example, in this case, you're trying to generalize the Tuple type -- that leads me to infer that your codebase contains many different kinds of tuples of different arities and types.

That strikes me as being a bit suspicious -- I would instead look into converting some of those tuples into either regular classes or (if you still need tuple-like functionality) a [namedtuple](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#named-tuples). [Dataclasses](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/additional_features.html#dataclasses) (which are new [as of Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)) could also be convenient here.

Those solutions would also help make your code a little more readable -- you can now give concrete names and meanings to each distinct kind of tuple.

Alternatively, if you have only a few distinct types of tuples but use those tuples all over the place, you could try using [type aliases](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#type-aliases) so you don't have to repeatedly re-type the same (long) type over and over. E.g. instead of doing:

```
def foo(x: Tuple[int, int, int, int]) -> None: ...
```

...you could do:

```
IpAddress = Tuple[int, int, int, int]

def foo(x: IpAddress) -> None: ...
```